# typescript does not notice property can not be null/undefined when using spreadoperator

Tags: typescript

Typescript does not recognise that the properties of an object are checked against null/undfined when i use the spread operator.

```
interface MyObject {
    date: SerializedDateTime;
    someId: number;
}

interface MyObjectInput {
    date?: Maybe<SerializedDateTime>;
    someId?: Maybe<number>;
}

function useMyObject(myObject: MyObject) {
    //Do something with myObject
}

function test(input: MyObjectInput) {

    if (!input.date) {
        throw new Error('Date not provided');
    }

    if (!input.someId) {
        throw new Error('SomeId not provided');
    }

    //This works...
    useMyObject({
        date: input.date,
        someId: input.someId,
    });

    //Here the compiler complains that the types are incompatible
    useMyObject({
        ...input
    });
}
```

The exact message is:

```
Types of property 'date' are incompatible.    
Type 'Maybe<Date>' is not assignable to type 'Date'.       
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Date'
```

I don't know why this happens. The properties are checked against null/undefined and therfore compatible as you can see when I don't use the spreadoperator. Does anybode know the cause of this problem and how to solve it?

Comment: You can use an assertion function: https://tsplay.dev/mbE79N or use a type guard: https://tsplay.dev/mAJlZW It looks like TypeScript is not capable of narrowing the object type as a whole, only its individual properties.

Comment: How should that work ? `useMyObject` need non defined objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is brought up in [ms/TS#42384](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384), where type narrowings of properties do not propagate to parent objects. The workaround described in the issue looks like:

```
function assertField<T extends { [field in Field]?: T[field] }, Field extends keyof T & string,>(
  obj: T,
  field: Field
): obj is T & { [field in Field]: NonNullable<T[field]> } {
  if (!obj[field]) false;
  return true;
}
```

```
if (!assertField(input, "date")) throw new Error("Date not provided")

if (!assertField(input, "someId")) throw new Error("SomeId not provided")

useMyObject({
    ...input, // okay
});
```

Some other workarounds include [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions),

```
function assertInput(input: MyObjectInput): asserts input is MyObject {
    if (!input.date) {
        throw new Error("Date not provided");
    }

    if (!input.someId) {
        throw new Error("SomeId not provided");
    }
}


function test(input: MyObjectInput) {
    assertInput(input);

    useMyObject({
        ...input, // okay
    });
}
```

and [type predicates (user-defined type guards)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

```
function isGoodInput(input: MyObjectInput): input is MyObject {
    if (!input.date) {
        throw new Error("Date not provided");
    }

    if (!input.someId) {
        throw new Error("SomeId not provided");
    }

    return true
}
```

[Playground (`assertField`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-gAiGiQH31Rp9KCyYbIEAQcMAUSgoagpR9-EgEdkRCsoYAbsAqDxA5IMU6XStoO7np7bWBfd0lIHg71Q+HIzG47IEz7GPIIEpU+mszm8-UCw58oVaiVSg6HBQAHRzr1VjHaIczIA)

[Playground (assertion function)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAjAVhBMZAbwChkLkATOSALmQGVpg4AbYALwioBFaIAFWABbCAG5ylAM4B7MQEkqDEAFcR2aJIC+pUqEixEKDDnyEFIAA6qiZStQEB+BqjjpNAHmZRWHbnwCwmIAfJIOcopULmjuXmoa0GGkuqQwqiCEwLIgyKrSEKZ4BGAAFCJYxYSuleZgAJQkUhQA9C28ssiREGAAFqAA5sgA7sB9yBVmJSl66Zlg2blw0gVQYJY2ZaCbNVMW1rb1DMurYNLI27YX50V1TQ7AMMilAISXYAB0NJCN9g6UfSgsmGyBAEBBAFEoECoKUAET8SCg2REKxAgBuwCoPDh9XClFSDyer3eH26Sl+zX+gOBoPByChMPhjHkECUyNRGKxOLxVN0qTmWRyyEg0i2BzAuyq6wllIcJ2gMs2pXevKp+UKtRKpT+-2QHwN7wANHzebogA)

[Playground (type guard)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAjAVhBMZAbwChkLkATOSALmQGVpg4AbYALwioBFaIAFWABbCAG5ylAM4B7MQEkqDEAFcR2aJIC+pUqEixEKDDnyEFIAA6qiZStQEB+BqjjpNAHmZRWHbnwCwmIAfJIOcopULmjuXmoa0GGkuqQwqiCEwLIgyKrSEKZ4BGAAFCJYxYSuleZgAJQkUhQA9C28ssiREGAAFqAA5sgA7sB9yBVmJSl66Zlg2bnA0gDisrJUljZloNs1UxbWtvUMu7bIy2i1JU0OwDDIpQCEZ2AAdDSQjfYOlH1QsmGyBAECBAFEoACoKUAET8SDA2REKwAgBuwCoPBh9XClFSdwez1eb26Sm+zV+-0BwNByAhUNhjHkECUiORaIxWJxFPxlCgPVUUFyYCgqggMzSGSyOWQkGkOyOYH2VTAW2Ot0o90eL1W602itKr3qjX5YEFIEkFPyhWuhFKP1+yDezteABoedzdEA)

Answer (score 1):

The property checks only narrow the properties, not the type of the object itself. This is a known shortcoming, and there are issues open on the TS GitHub repo.

A workaround for now is to check them using a typeguard that narrows the type of the object:

```js
/**
 * Removes optionality and `undefined` from the property.
 */
function checkProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(
  value: T,
  key: K
): value is T & { [key in K]-?: T[K] } {
  return value[key] !== undefined
}

function test(input: MyObjectInput) {
  if (!checkProperty(input, "date")) {
    throw new Error("Date not provided")
  }

  if (!checkProperty(input, "someId")) {
    throw new Error("SomeId not provided")
  }

  useMyObject({
    date: input.date,
    someId: input.someId,
  })

  useMyObject({
    ...input,
  })
}
```

[TS playground for the above](https://tsplay.dev/WKp1zw)

Or, as @vr. said in their comment on your question, you can put all the checks in a type guard function, to assert that that the input is of type `MyObject`.